# How can I use ng-repeat to access an array outside of the current array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the data I'm using.  It's 3 different arrays.

```
"areas": {
  "default": [
    {
      "area": "Master Bedroom",
      "uuid": "986e3f42-1797-49ae-b060-181a33b9",
      "description": "",
      "new": [
        {
          "value": "986e3f42-1797-49ae-b060-181a33b9",
          "label": "Master Bedroom",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "value": "0c7abecb-6078-4718-8537-97a0d8ea",
          "label": "Bedroom",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "value": "95de4e05-a5f4-4d67-bd8b-cb3906c4",
          "label": "Powder Room",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "value": "b4e794b2-7a5f-4567-9422-cb1c67c8",
          "label": "Kitchen",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "value": null,
          "label": "Select",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "area": "Kitchen",
      "uuid": "b4e794b2-7a5f-4567-9422-cb1c67c8",
      "description": "",
      "new": [
        {
          "value": "986e3f42-1797-49ae-b060-181a33b9",
          "label": "Master Bedroom",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "value": "0c7abecb-6078-4718-8537-97a0d8ea",
          "label": "Bedroom",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "value": "95de4e05-a5f4-4d67-bd8b-cb3906c4",
          "label": "Powder Room",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "value": "b4e794b2-7a5f-4567-9422-cb1c67c8",
          "label": "Kitchen",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "value": null,
          "label": "Select",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "new": [
    {
      "value": "986e3f42-1797-49ae-b060-181a33b9",
      "label": "Master Bedroom",
      "selected": false
    },
    {
      "value": "b4e794b2-7a5f-4567-9422-cb1c67c8",
      "label": "Kitchen",
      "selected": false
    },
    {
      "value": null,
      "label": "Select",
      "selected": true
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the `default`, and `new` arrays are nested inside the `areas` object.  I'm trying to display the areas in the `default` array, but also be able to create new areas using the data/labels in the `new` array.  However, I don't know if Angular will let me repeat for an array that is outside of the array I'm currently repeating through.  Does anyone know a better way to do this, or a better way to arrange the data?

Comment: yes, you're correct.  I meant to type "object" there.

Comment: This description is really vague, providing an expected output would sure help

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do but if you're working with same indexes in both `default` and `new` array you could have something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in areas.default">
    {{item.value}} <!-- This is from areas.default array -->
    {{areas.new[$index].value}} <!-- This is from areas.new array -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can (pseudo):

```
<div ng-repeat="default in areas.default">
 <div ng-repeat="new in default.new">
   <div ng-repeat="obj in new">
    {{ obj.value}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```